# Adding new rows in table programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to solve a problem with creating new rows when user will complete all mini-games each day.

Code should save today's score to variable (I'm using Sharedpreferences) and if previous row has value diferrent than zero then save this variable to next row.
**The goal is that user can track his progress.**

What I did is it saves scores from all 4 games to one row and saves today's date as well. I'm sure that these multiple variables like rtsPointsView1,2,3 etc. are useless and I could write it in more efficient way but I don't know how.

How to create table which shows correctly user's progress?

MyProgressActivity.java

```
package com.pracainzynierska.inzynierka;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.pracainzynierska.inzynierka.R;

import java.util.Locale;


public class MyProgressActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView usernameView, rtsPointsView1, mcPointsView1, gPointsView1, fttPointsView1, dateView1, totalScoreView, myProgressView,
                            rtsPointsView2, mcPointsView2, gPointsView2, fttPointsView2, dateView2,
                            rtsPointsView3, mcPointsView3, gPointsView3, fttPointsView3, dateView3,
                            rtsPointsView4, mcPointsView4, gPointsView4, fttPointsView4, dateView4,
                            rtsPointsView5, mcPointsView5, gPointsView5, fttPointsView5, dateView5,
                            rtsPointsView6, mcPointsView6, gPointsView6, fttPointsView6, dateView6,
                            rtsPointsView7, mcPointsView7, gPointsView7, fttPointsView7, dateView7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_progress);
        String user = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        usernameView = findViewById(R.id.username_myprogress);
        usernameView.setText("" + user);

        //region findViewById region
        rtsPointsView1 = findViewById(R.id.rts_score_1);
        mcPointsView1 = findViewById(R.id.mc_score_1);
        gPointsView1 = findViewById(R.id.g_score_1);
        fttPointsView1 = findViewById(R.id.ftt_score_1);
        dateView1 = findViewById(R.id.date);

        rtsPointsView2 = findViewById(R.id.rts_score_2);
        mcPointsView2 = findViewById(R.id.mc_score_2);
        gPointsView2= findViewById(R.id.g_score_2);
        fttPointsView2 = findViewById(R.id.ftt_score_2);
        dateView2 = findViewById(R.id.date2);

        rtsPointsView2 = findViewById(R.id.rts_score_2);
        mcPointsView2 = findViewById(R.id.mc_score_2);
        gPointsView2 = findViewById(R.id.g_score_2);
        fttPointsView2 = findViewById(R.id.ftt_score_2);
        dateView2 = findViewById(R.id.date2);

        rtsPointsView3 = findViewById(R.id.rts_score_3);
        mcPointsView3 = findViewById(R.id.mc_score_3);
        gPointsView3 = findViewById(R.id.g_score_3);
        fttPointsView3 = findViewById(R.id.ftt_score_3);
        dateView3 = findViewById(R.id.date3);

        rtsPointsView4 = findViewById(R.id.rts_score_4);
        mcPointsView4 = findViewById(R.id.mc_score_4);
        gPointsView4 = findViewById(R.id.g_score_4);
        fttPointsView4 = findViewById(R.id.ftt_score_4);
        dateView4 = findViewById(R.id.date4);

        rtsPointsView5 = findViewById(R.id.rts_score_5);
        mcPointsView5 = findViewById(R.id.mc_score_5);
        gPointsView5 = findViewById(R.id.g_score_5);
        fttPointsView5 = findViewById(R.id.ftt_score_5);
        dateView5 = findViewById(R.id.date5);

        rtsPointsView6 = findViewById(R.id.rts_score_6);
        mcPointsView6 = findViewById(R.id.mc_score_6);
        gPointsView6 = findViewById(R.id.g_score_6);
        fttPointsView6 = findViewById(R.id.ftt_score_6);
        dateView6 = findViewById(R.id.date6);

        rtsPointsView7 = findViewById(R.id.rts_score_7);
        mcPointsView7 = findViewById(R.id.mc_score_7);
        gPointsView7 = findViewById(R.id.g_score_7);
        fttPointsView7 = findViewById(R.id.ftt_score_7);
        dateView7 = findViewById(R.id.date7);

        totalScoreView = findViewById(R.id.totalScoreView);
        myProgressView = findViewById(R.id.myProgressView);

        // endregion findViewById region


        SharedPreferences preferences =  this.getSharedPreferences(usernameView.getText().toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int rts_score = preferences.getInt("rts_score",0);
        int mc_score = preferences.getInt("mc_score",0);
        int g_score = preferences.getInt("g_score",0);
        int ftt_score = preferences.getInt("ftt_score",0);
        int dailyChallengeScore = preferences.getInt("dailychallenge_score",0);
        int total_score = rts_score + mc_score + g_score + ftt_score + dailyChallengeScore;
        String rts_date = preferences.getString("date","-");

        AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        Typeface logoFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(am, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "fonts/%s","FjallaOne-Regular.ttf"));
        Typeface myProgressFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(am, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "fonts/%s","Montserrat-Regular.ttf"));
        myProgressView.setTypeface(logoFont);
        myProgressView.setText("My Progress");

        //region setTypeface & setText

        rtsPointsView1.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        rtsPointsView1.setText("" + rts_score);

        mcPointsView1.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        mcPointsView1.setText("" + mc_score);

        gPointsView1.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        gPointsView1.setText("" + g_score);

        fttPointsView1.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        fttPointsView1.setText("" + ftt_score);

        dateView1.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        dateView1.setText("" + rts_date);

        rtsPointsView2.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        rtsPointsView2.setText("" + rts_score);

        mcPointsView2.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        mcPointsView2.setText("" + mc_score);

        gPointsView2.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        gPointsView2.setText("" + g_score);

        fttPointsView2.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        fttPointsView2.setText("" + ftt_score);

        dateView2.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        dateView2.setText("" + rts_date);

        rtsPointsView3.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        rtsPointsView3.setText("" + rts_score);

        mcPointsView3.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        mcPointsView3.setText("" + mc_score);

        gPointsView3.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        gPointsView3.setText("" + g_score);

        fttPointsView3.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        fttPointsView3.setText("" + ftt_score);

        dateView3.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        dateView3.setText("" + rts_date);

        rtsPointsView4.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        rtsPointsView4.setText("" + rts_score);

        mcPointsView4.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        mcPointsView4.setText("" + mc_score);

        gPointsView4.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        gPointsView4.setText("" + g_score);

        fttPointsView4.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        fttPointsView4.setText("" + ftt_score);

        dateView4.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        dateView4.setText("" + rts_date);

        rtsPointsView5.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        rtsPointsView5.setText("" + rts_score);

        mcPointsView5.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        mcPointsView5.setText("" + mc_score);

        gPointsView5.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        gPointsView5.setText("" + g_score);

        fttPointsView5.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        fttPointsView5.setText("" + ftt_score);

        dateView5.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        dateView5.setText("" + rts_date);

        rtsPointsView6.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        rtsPointsView6.setText("" + rts_score);

        mcPointsView6.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        mcPointsView6.setText("" + mc_score);

        gPointsView6.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        gPointsView6.setText("" + g_score);

        fttPointsView6.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        fttPointsView6.setText("" + ftt_score);

        dateView6.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        dateView6.setText("" + rts_date);

        rtsPointsView7.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        rtsPointsView7.setText("" + rts_score);

        mcPointsView7.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        mcPointsView7.setText("" + mc_score);

        gPointsView7.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        gPointsView7.setText("" + g_score);

        fttPointsView7.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        fttPointsView7.setText("" + ftt_score);

        dateView7.setTypeface(myProgressFont);
        dateView7.setText("" + rts_date);

        totalScoreView.setTypeface(logoFont);
        totalScoreView.setText("Total score: " + total_score);


        //endregion setTypeface & setText


    }
}
```

activity_my_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    tools:context="com.pracainzynierska.inzynierka.MyProgressActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/myprogressTable"
        android:layout_width="416dp"
        android:layout_height="534dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow android:layout_height="60dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hitLabel"
                android:layout_width="49dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Remember The Sequence"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/errorLabel"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="MathChain"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/geomemotry_table"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Geomemotry"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fillthetext_table"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Fill The Text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date1"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rts_score_1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mc_score_1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/g_score_1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ftt_score_1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rts_score_2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mc_score_2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/g_score_2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ftt_score_2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date3"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rts_score_3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mc_score_3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/g_score_3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ftt_score_3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date4"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rts_score_4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mc_score_4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/g_score_4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ftt_score_4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date5"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rts_score_5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mc_score_5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/g_score_5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ftt_score_5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date6"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rts_score_6"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mc_score_6"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/g_score_6"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ftt_score_6"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date7"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rts_score_7"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mc_score_7"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/g_score_7"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ftt_score_7"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myProgressView"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_myprogress"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalScoreView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myprogressTable"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

One of games' save

```
//method for saving. It looks almost the same in every mini-game

private void saveScore() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(usernameView.getText().toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("rts_score",player_points);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: I think that the best approach is to use ListView and update it through ListAdapter. Take a look at this tutorial:https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html